# Mapping a dictionary to NAN rows of a column in Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, dictionary

Here as shown below is a data frame , where in a column `col2` many nan's are there , i want to fill that only nan value the `col1` as key from dictionary dict_map and map those value in col2.

#### Reproducible code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    dict_map = {'a':45,'b':23,'c':97,'z': -1}
    df =  pd.DataFrame()
    df['tag'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
    df['col1'] = ['a','b','c','b','a','a','z','c','b','c','b']
    df['col2'] = [np.nan,909,34,56,np.nan,45,np.nan,11,61,np.nan,np.nan]
    df['_'] = df['col1'].map(dict_map)
```

#### Expected Output

[image]

#### One of the Method is :

```
df['col3'] =  np.where(df['col2'].isna(),df['_'],df['col2'])
df
```

Just wanted to know any other method using function and map function , we can optimize this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map `col1` with your `dict_map` and then use that as input to `fillna`, as follows

```py
df['col3'] = df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'].map(dict_map))
```

Comment: I like this solution. I wonder if it is faster than just using `list comprehension`.

Comment: @P.Pinho - I think yes. In pandas golden rule is not use loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the very same result just using `list comprehension`, it is a very pythonic solution and I believe it holds better performance.

We are just reading `col2` and copying the value to `col3` if its not `NaN`. Then, if it is, we look into `Col1`, grab the `dict key` and, instead, use the corresponding value from `dict_map`.

```
df['col3'] = [df['col2'][idx] if not np.isnan(df['col2'][idx]) else dict_map[df['col1'][idx]] for idx in df.index.tolist()]
```

Output:

```
df

   tag  col1     col2    col3
 0   1     a      NaN    45.0
 1   2     b    909.0   909.0
 2   3     c     34.0    34.0
 3   4     b     56.0    56.0
 4   5     a      NaN    45.0
 5   6     a     45.0    45.0
 6   7     z      NaN    -1.0
 7   8     c     11.0    11.0
 8   9     b     61.0    61.0
 9  10     c      NaN    97.0
10  11     b      NaN    23.0
```